# Not able to send http headers in array ? how to send multiple objects in array?

Tags: angular

Trying to send array in `http headers`. I have create a `HTTP Interceptor` for request response handling.
My `interceptor.ts` file like following in that I have send header as `key value` pair its work in these code. But i want to send it in array with objects.

```
sessionParam:any = {
    param1:{'name':'ttt', 'lname':'test'},
    param2:{'name':'aaa', 'lname':'aaa'},
    param3:{'name':'bbb', 'lname':'bbb'}
}
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    for (var val in this.sessionParam) {
        Object.keys(this.sessionParam[val]).forEach(key => {
            headers = headers.set(key,this.sessionParam[val][key]);
        });
    }

    request = request.clone({           
        url: `${environment.baseUrl}${request.url}`,
        headers: headers
    })
    return next.handle(request);
}
```

I want to send all object in single array
How to passed multiple objects in single array ?

Comment: what error you are getting or issue?

Comment: I faced the same problem a while back and as a Workaround I did this:   `request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: aValue,
                        AnotherHeader: anotherValue,
   
                    },
                });`

Comment: I don't have any issue. now i am sending header as ` key value ` format

Answer (score 0):

You should change `headers.set` by `headers.append` method.

```
 for (var val in this.sessionParam) {
        Object.keys(this.sessionParam[val]).forEach(key => {
            headers.append(key,this.sessionParam[val][key]);
        });
}
```

Update:

Your parameter need follow `HttpHeader` parameters list.

```
sessionParam:any = {
    param1:{'name':'responseType', 'value':'blob'},
    param2:{'name':'Authorization', 'value':'Bearer'},
}
```

Comment: dont need, you can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805542/angular-httpclient-append-headers-to-httpheaders

Comment: its just a object, when i am console `headers` i have also show same format but in send as a key value format

Comment: i have also get same output you can check `[[Entries]]: Array(33)
0: {"userid" => Array(1)}
1: {"username" => Array(1)}
2: {"parentbank" => Array(1)}
3: {"parentbranch" => Array(1)}
4: {"multicurrency" => Array(3)}
5: {"iscashtell" => Array(1)}
6: {"ishc" => Array(1)}
7: {"lang" => Array(1)}`

Comment: you should change your session param, http header should append some key like this  headers.append('Authorization','Bearer ' + currentUser.access_token);
            headers.append('responseType', 'blob');