# Angular HttpHeaders is not setting value

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to set headers for one of the get request. Following is the function:

```
 getLeads(jwtToken: string): Observable<any>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const authroizationToken = 'bearer '.concat(jwtToken);
    console.log(authroizationToken);          ------------------>  prints the token
    headers.append('Authorization', authroizationToken);
    console.log(headers.get('Authorization'));  ---------------------> this prints null
    var result = this.http.get<Leads>(this.getLeadsUrl, {headers});
    return result;
  }
```

But heades.get('Authorization') is null for some reason and I am not able to figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question has already been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47805759/2358409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `.append` returns the new headers objects. try this it works as expected. Just make sure you assign the headers back to the variable everytime you append a new header.

```
   getLeads(jwtToken: string) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const authroizationToken = 'bearer '.concat(jwtToken);
    console.log(authroizationToken);
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', authroizationToken);
    console.log(headers.get('Authorization'));
  }
```

Here is a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tby6dg)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your code:

```
getLeads(jwtToken: string): Observable<any>{
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': `bearer ${jwtToken}` })
    };
    return  this.http.get<Leads>(this.getLeadsUrl, httpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set()`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#set) method of HttpHeaders:

> Which sets or modifies a value for a given header in a clone of the original instance. If the header already exists, it's value is replaced with the given value in the returned object.

An example:

```
let header = new HttpHeaders().set(
  "Authorization",`bearer ${jwtToken}`
);

return this.http.get<Leads>(this.getLeadsUrl,  {headers:header});
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has answers in the following threads.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45286959/12376898

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47805759/12376898

To sum it up, the headers are immutable, hence making any changes creates a new object. Unless you reference the newly created object to the old reference, only the old object persists.

```
getLeads(jwtToken: string) {
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('ANYHEADER','SOMESTRING') // will be lost
headers = headers.append('ANYHEADER','SOMESTRING') //unless you reference it again to the old reference
}
```